# Обновление неуникальной записи, иначе вставка новой

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица следующей структуры:

- **`id`** (`PK`, `AI`)
- **`uq1`** (`unique`)
- **`uq2`** (`unique`)
- **`count`**

Нужно сделать примерно следующее:

```
IF (NEW.uq1 = uq1 AND NEW uq2 = uq2) THEN count=count+1 ELSE INSERT VALUES ...
```

То есть нужно инкрементировать **`count`**, если сочетание **`uq1`** и **`uq2`** уже есть в таблице. В противном случае вставить новую запись

Конструкция вида

```
INSERT INTO [table] VALUES (NULL, NEW.uq1, NEW.uq2, 1, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1;
```

работает не совсем так, как ожидается. То есть она инкрементирует поле, даже если только одно из полей совпадает с табличным.

Как выйти из ситуации?

Comment: почитать про хранимые процедуры?

Comment: В Оракле для этого используют исключения. Если возникает искдючение "неуникальности", то ...

Comment: работает то оно как раз именно так как и ожидается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для выполнения этой задачи самым простым путем необходимо изменить структуру таблицы на следующую:

```
id(PK,AI)
uq1,uq2(unique) (сдвоенный индекс)
count
```

Comment: Да, спасибо. Сдвоенное уникальное поле и сдвоенный индекс помогли) Заработала конструкция, описанная в вопросе.